# Getting savedInstanceState null every time in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone explain me below code.why I am getting this issue?

issue video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16PzSn9zHhv-24hM5Vi_V-VQxtmA2PnSt/view?usp=sharing

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"not null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

I have create new black project and add above code in my MainActiviy and after I have create apk and upload on drive. 
  After that I have download that apk and start app first time getting "null" ,after that I have move that app into background and again I have open that app from app launcher icon again I showing "null" toast 
 After I have close that app forcefully and again open   app from launcher icon again I got "null" toast after again I have put that app in background again I have open that app from app launcher icon but this time on create not calling and I not getting any toast from above code when I close app forcefully after app restart from resume state but first time when I download and start app from launcher icon that time app launcher from stating. 
 Above issue not happen when I am directly install app from android studio.
 If I am installing app directly from studio that time only first time null show after every time app open from onresume state(oncreate) not call.

Can anyone explain me why this issue happen.

Comment: Kindly first understand [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). In same link they have explained savedInstanceState as well. I would suggest after understanding create a demo with just Activities, override all the Lifecycle just print logs and understand which methods are called in different scenario. Also do same exercise with Activity and Fragments to understand Lifecycle of Fragment.

Comment: All I can understand is, you are always trying to get the values from `Bundle` received in `onCreate()`  which is always null. Yes, it is always supposed to be null until and unless you override `onSaveInstanceState()` method, and put some values in its bundle.

Comment: @iCantC but when i am close app forcefully after oncreate not calling. My issue is that when i download every time oncreate call and showing null but when i close app forcefully after oncreate not call.

Comment: I strongly support what @ShadowDroid said above. You should go through the docs first.

Comment: please check video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16PzSn9zHhv-24hM5Vi_V-VQxtmA2PnSt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have check Lifecycler but it's not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

First you should read [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), what you want is to detect when the app is coming from background to foreground, Android actually have `onResume()` method for that.

`SaveInstanceState` is mostly used in orientation changes if you want to hold to the data because when orientation is changed the activity will be created again and `onCreate()` will be called. So we save the data in `InstanceState` and get that in `onCreate()` to resume the state.

Comment: Nope you didn't get the issue actually he has an issue  like whenever app installed from the APK from device storage(Not installed from the Android Studio) In that case on first launch app all the life cycle method works perfect when app goes in background and after that if we open that app from the launcher icon it will recall all the activity lifecycle again.Ideally it should call onResume only.Also this issue comes on the very first time if you kill the app and reopen it then this will not happen

Comment: Android OS actually have a default garbage collector kind of thing which remove the instance of the app even if it is in background so if your app is in background and you open it after some time, it will start as a new instance of app.